# spring data mongodb embeded query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

```
{
"_id" : "7959305563",
"_class" : "com.loylty.messagingEngine.entities.message.GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport",
"DATA_LIST" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "7959305562-1",
        "mobile" : "9566337867",
        "status" : "DELIVRD",
        "senttime" : "2018-01-09 14:19:42",
        "dlrtime" : "2018-01-09 14:57:06",
        "custom" : "9566337867"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "7959305562-2",
        "mobile" : "9566337867",
        "status" : "DELIVRD",
        "senttime" : "2018-01-09 14:19:42",
        "dlrtime" : "2018-01-09 14:57:05",
        "custom" : "9566337867"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "7959305562-3",
        "mobile" : "9566337867",
        "status" : "DELIVRD",
        "senttime" : "2018-01-09 14:19:42",
        "dlrtime" : "2018-01-09 14:57:04",
        "custom" : "9566337867"
    }
 ]
}
```

Structure of GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport

```
@Document(collection = "GROUP_ID_DELIVERY_STATUS")
public class GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport {

@Id
@Field("GROUP_ID")
private String groupId;

@Field("DATA_LIST")
private List<SolInfiniGroupIdData> data;

public String getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}

public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}

public List<SolInfiniGroupIdData> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<SolInfiniGroupIdData> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

Please forgive me If I am unable to describe properly.

This is the structure of my collection name GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport

I want to query in this collection and get the count of list in (DATA_LIST) of those having status  **DELIVRD**

Count should come as 3 for the given structure.

How should I do this in spring data mongodb criteria query ?

I wrote the shell query which is giving the proper count  but stuck in converting to criteria

```
db.getCollection('GROUP_ID_DELIVERY_STATUS').aggregate(
    { "$unwind" : "$DATA_LIST"},
    {
        "$match" : {"DATA_LIST.status": "DELIVRD" }
    },
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
)
```

This is how I wrote

```
package com.loylty.messagingEngine.service.Impl;

import com.loylty.messagingEngine.service.GroupIdDeliveryStatusReportService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

@Service
public class GroupIdDeliveryStatusReportServiceImpl implements 
GroupIdDeliveryStatusReportService {

@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

@Override
public void getDeliveryCount() {
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            //match(Criteria.where("_id").in("7959305563")), //Use this if you want to do this operation for particular document only
            unwind("DATA_LIST"),
            match(Criteria.where("DATA_LIST.status").is("DELIVRD")),
            project("DATA_LIST._id")
    );
    AggregationResults<String> groupResults
            = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport", String.class);
    int count = groupResults.getMappedResults().size();

}
}
```

Comment: there can be many documents with DATA_LIST.status = DELIVRD  right? SO if there are two documents where document1 has three DELIVRD and document2 has teo DELIVRD, then the output should be 5 is that correct?

Comment: @pvpkiran yes there can be multiple documents inside DATA_LIST with different status. I want to get the count of those documents (inside DATA_LIST)

Comment: I understand there can be many entries inside DATA_LIST. But can there be many documents with DATA_LIST?

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes there can be many documents with DATA_LIST.  SO if there are two documents where document1 has three DELIVRD and document2 has teo DELIVRD, then the output should be 5 is that correct?  Yes correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        //match(Criteria.where("_id").in("7959305563")), Use this if you want to do this operation for particular document only
        unwind("DATA_LIST"),
        match(Criteria.where("DATA_LIST.status").is("DELIVRD"))
        project("DATA_LIST._id")
    );

AggregationResults<String> groupResults
        = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport", String.class);
    int count = groupResults.getMappedResults().size();
```

Comment: please see my edits . I have tried writing shell query and its giving proper count as of now but stuck in converting that to criteria query

Comment: did you try to debug. What are you getting in groupResults? Are you using my code as it is? what is the type of `_id` is it String? For me its working perfectly fine

Comment: yes type of _id is String. I have edited the post update the structure of GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport

Comment: try without the project. and try to debug what you get in groupedResults

Comment: mappedResults size is zero

Comment: I asked what does groupResults (and not mappedResults )has after the query. Did you debug

Comment: yes I debugged . groupResults  showing 3 parameters while debuggin one is mappedResult , second is rawResult , third is serverUsed.  mappedResult size is 0 . and rawResult has size 2

Comment: I am not sure . whether this is creating issue or not . but instead of mongoTemplate I am using MongoOperations

Comment: You collection name is `GROUP_ID_DELIVERY_STATUS`(@Document....). And in the aggregate code i sent you, I have put collection Name as `GroupIdDeliveryStatusReport`. What is the correct colelction name. use that in the aggregate function.

Comment: Wooh It worked. Thanks A lot ! :) . Sorry for silly mistake but this is the first time I am using spring and mongodb